# Set style for li:before

Tags: css

I'm adding a character with the `:before` CSS selector to a list

```
li:before {
    content: "■";
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    vertical-align: 20%;
}
```

I want to underline the content of the list item but not the content before so I added:

```
li {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However the `:before` part still gets underlined even though its `text-decoration` is set to `none`.

**How can I underline the list text but not the before part?**

JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/fX86Q/

*Side note: My goal was not to add anything to the html and find a CSS only solution. That's why I didn't choose @mahatmanich (obvious) solution*

Comment: In firefox and chrome you can add `display: inline-block` to  `li:before`.

Comment: @canon: Yep, works in Opera and Safari too. But not on IE10.

Comment: @canon That's my favorite solution. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: My update should work for you in all browsers!

Comment: @Horen added as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firefox, chrome, and opera you can add `display: inline-block` to `li:before` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/fX86Q/11/)).

```
li:before {
    content: "■";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-decoration: none !important; /* this should no longer be necessary */
    vertical-align: 20%;
}
```

This won't work in IE, though.

Comment: That's bad isn't it? How many IE programmers do you need to change a light bulb? Answer: None, they define dark as a new standard :D

Answer (score 4):

Since the `li` style always applies to the entire `<li>` element, you need to use another html element like a `<span>` inside the `<li>` and apply

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><span>Test</span></li>
    <li><span>Test</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li:before  {
    content: "■";
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: 20%;
}
li span {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Even better without class:
http://jsfiddle.net/fX86Q/8/

Comment: Thanks - that's a good solution but I was explicetly looking for a solution with the `:before` selector

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, why would you underline a list item? Surely that should be on an anchor link?

Comment: This should do! li have no underline as default so you would not need that!

Answer (score 1):

If you are styling the way list bullets are there you can you this instead of **li:before**

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2 </li>
</ul>

ul {list-style-type: square;}
li {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Hope this helps too! jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/xWwXq/

Comment: Explicitly with the :before he said!

Comment: It's a nice solution ;-) 1up, but not the one he wants!

Comment: yes the li:before seems complecated to style list item bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Update li:before CSS part

```
li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "■";
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    vertical-align: 20%;
}
```

This resolves your problem. jsFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/SqkjF/

Comment: Not in IE <= 10. That's why I didn't post it as an answer.